# Can I define a hashmap differently to it's declaration

Tags: java, hashmap

What I would like to do is have a map that actually holds values as one thing, but is declared as another e.g. actually hold the value as String, but put/get will use Integer...

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
```

I can use this map with

```
map.put("A","1");
String ret = map.get("A");
```

but this will get me a String, and I need to 'put' in a String too.

What I would like is for the put/get methods to accept an Integer value (but the map still stores ...

```
map.put("A",1);
Integer ret = map.get("A");
```

How can I achieve this?

N.B. this isn't exclusively for String/Integer conversion, but just conversion between any types.

Thanks.

Comment: Map<String, String> means "a map containing Strings as keys, and Strings as values". You want a map containing strings as keys, and Integers as values. What do you deduce?

Comment: Sorry what? I would like to open an Orange shop and sell Oranges **but** I want to accept deliveries of Bananas. And what will you do with those Bananas?

Comment: The map is there to store and retrieve values. It does not do type conversion between various types of objects.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Object` as the value type. It can store `String`, `Integer`, `Double`, for that matter almost anything. But you need to be very careful when using `Object` because you'll have to cast each value you get from the map accordingly(else you'll always get a `ClassCastException`).

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

FYI, I do not recommended you to use this. Instead be sure what your `Map` has to hold and have the value type accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Simply

```
Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can (but not SHOULD use, really) this critter: https://gist.github.com/eltabo/8953176. Really... it's evil.
Only for educational purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Why should someone want to store a value in a different representation than the value is made out of? You still can create a string out of an integer and reverse after obtaining it from the map, but what is your advantage?